# .Net 4.5 and Azure

Tags: .net, azure

Does anyone know when Azure will support .NET 4.5 Framework for site hosting and database migrations?

I searched around for a day, and realized there are workarounds:

- Via web worker role

Does anyone know when Microsoft will make .Net 4.5 available on all services on Azure?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's on October 2012 (FYI)

Answer (score 3):

As [Scott mentioned](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/09/17/announcing-great-improvements-to-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx) the support for .net 4.5 in Windows Azure is scheduled for next month, that is all you will get.

The fact is product release dates are not discussed on forums or Q/A as release of a product is important for any team. Such information is available mostly on the product specific site or someone associated with that product blog. Once release date is set either their will be an announcement about its release or you just see the product release along with announcement all together.

Answer (score 2):

> We’ll have even more new features and enhancements coming in the weeks
>   ahead – including support for the recent Windows Server 2012 and .NET
>   4.5 releases (we will enable new web and worker role images with Windows Server 2012 and .NET 4.5 next month).  Keep an eye out on my
>   blog for details as these new features become available.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/09/17/announcing-great-improvements-to-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx

Update 8 October 2012:

> We’ll have even more new features and enhancements coming later this
>   month – including support for the recent Windows Server 2012 and .NET
>   4.5 releases (we will enable new web and worker role images with Windows Server 2012 and .NET 4.5, and support .NET 4.5 with Websites).

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2012/10/07/announcing-improvements-to-the-windows-azure-portal.aspx

Comment: Nobody knows. Soon enough though. I'll be at the Microsoft office tomorrow, I will ask around for you (if I don't forget it) :-)

Comment: Nobody could tell me anything... NDA I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with a MS evangelist and he says they are in the 90 days testing. There is no official hard date set yet.
I was hoping to get it before my production deployment too but it did not happen, so now I downgraded to 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Vote for .net 4.5/IIS8 in Windows Azure here
http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2598170-iis8-and-asp-net-4-5-support-in-azure-platform

The more votes the more Microsoft will pay attention and develop for it

**EDIT**
I received an email from Microsoft to say they will soon support applications built on .net 4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 on the cloud.

Comment: They already stated that they are working on it, so voting for it is useless.